# How to convert polars series to pandas series in python?

Tags: python, python-polars

How to convert polars series to pandas series in python?

My current workaround is:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,2], "b":[2,2,3], "c":[1,2,3]})
df[["a"]].to_pandas()["a"]
```

But is there a way to do it directly from polars series to pandas series?

Why I need this is because I feed the data into statmodels.OLS and want to have variable names instead of numbers for variables. And when I feed the data into statmodels.OLS directly from polars I get the following error:

```
unrecognized data structures: <class 'polars.internals.series.Series'> / <class 'polars.internals.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `polars>=0.13.9`

```py
pl.Series([1, 2, 3]).to_pandas()
```

For `polars<=0.13.8`

```py
pl.Series([1, 2, 3]).to_arrow().to_pandas()
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for adding the function! The path through arrow is also interesting. I did not know that arrow series could be converted to pandas series.

Comment: This requires pandas>=2 though, correct? I currently get `ModuleNotFoundError: pa.Table requires 'pyarrow' module to be installed` even though I have pyarrow==13.0.0